# Is there any possibility to retrieve files from a corrupted os in Virtual box?

Tags: virtual-machine

[image]

Below is the picture attached of the corrupted os in Virtual Box. I need the files in that vdi.

Host OS - Win10
OS - Ubuntu 17.1 
VDI 
dynamically allocated.

Any way to get the files back?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

- Checkout answers in [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893306/how-can-i-extract-files-from-vdi?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- An easier approach is to make the corrupted vm boot from a linux live cd/dvd(Mint, Ubuntu e.t.c). After this you can navigate to vm's the file-system( which is not other than the vdi). I haven't tried this before but I think a corrupted vm does not differ from a corrupted install in a physical machine.

Hope that any of the above will help you!